# Tableau Column Difference - as a dimension

Tags: tableau-api

I am looking for difference of two columns in Tableau. I have the formula with me.

```
IF ATTR([Valuation Profile]) = "Base" THEN 
LOOKUP(ZN(SUM([Value])), 1) > - ZN(LOOKUP(SUM([Value]),0)) END
```

But I get it as a separate column in the columns sections. How do I get that in the rows section? Basically how to get the difference as a dimension?

Please see attached images of what I want and what I have. Apparently, I cannot upload my excel sheet and tableau worksheet here. So I have upload just the screenshots.

[What I have - vs - What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUjQ6.png)

[Tableau Workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQh1b.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: https://community.tableau.com/message/627171#627171

Use LOD expression to calculate the individual values first. 
Create calculated fields 'BASE', 'CSA' and 'CSA-BASE' as below.

**BASE:**

{FIXED [Book Name]: SUM( if [Valuation Profile] = 'BASE' then Value else 0 end ) }

**CSA:**

{FIXED [Book Name]: SUM( if [Valuation Profile] = 'CSA' then Value else 0 end ) }

**CSA-BASE**

[CSA]-[BASE]

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XWSF.png)

Answer (score 1):

First off, there is no way that you can generate additional rows for your data in Tableau!
In your case however you could use a workaround and do the following:

- Create a calculated field for BASE and one for CSA. The formula should
  be `IF [Valuation Profile] = 'BASE' THEN [Value] END` and `IF
  [Valuation Profile] = 'CSA' THEN [Value] END` respectively
- Afterwards you can drag Measure Names onto your rows shelf and
- replace the `SUM([Value])` with your two newly created calculated fields

that should give you all three measures in different rows in your table

Comment: Thank you Alexander. Your approach kind of worked. Michel from Tableau community helped me solve the problem with just a little extension to your approach. Please see below.